# JQuery not called from form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying the best I can to make a form, where I check in my database if the webshop name exist, but I am running my head to the wall right now. So a user set in a name in the form. If the webshop exist the error: "The Webshop name is not avaible" in a span below the form.

Nothing of this code is working right now, so I have of course made some mistakes, but where should I start looking? The database connection is working fine, and I am not getting any errors in my Developer console.

Best Regards

```
<form group="form-horizontal" id="webshopform" action="createWebshop.php" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
       <label for="Webshop-Succes">Webshop Name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="createWebshopInput">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
 </form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#webshopform').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
            fields: {
                createWebshopInput: {
                    remote {
                        message: 'The Webshop name is not avaible',
                        url: 'webshopcheck.php',
                        data: "dbconfic.inc.php",
                        dataType: 'json'
                    }

                }
            }
    });
});
```

webshopcheck.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include 'dbconfic.inc.php';

if(isset($_POST['createWebshopInput']) && $_POST['createWebshopInput'] != '')
    {
        $response = array();
        $shop = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['createWebshopInput']);
        $sql  = "SELECT name FROM webshops";
        $res    = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
        $count  = mysqli_num_rows($res);
        if($count > 0)
        {
            $response['status'] = false;
            $response['msg'] = 'Webshop Already Exist.';
        }
        else
        {
            $response['status'] = true;
            $response['msg'] = 'Webshop available.';
        }
         echo json_encode($response);
    }?>
```

Comment: @wahwahwah "Nothing of this code is working right now" -> On Code Review, this question is off topic.

Comment: You know what, it cannot be true that my question is off topic from php, qjuery and html because I say "Nothing of this code is working right now".

Comment: I was just making an edit on my question, so people could see that I edited Fred.

Comment: Omg it is like children in here. There is never ever ever place for mistakes or any misunderstandings in here. Maybe that is just how boys are, I dont know. But anyhow Tjons suggestion worked, so at least one person in here could figure out what I meant......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with the jQuery plugin that you are using, but a perfunctory glance through the docs showed that you are missing the `validators` key/object in your configuration.

Here's an (untested) example of how your Javascript should probably look:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#webshopform').formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
        fields: {
            createWebshopInput: {
                validators: {
                    remote: {
                        message: 'The Webshop name is not avaible',
                        url: 'webshopcheck.php',
                        data: "dbconfic.inc.php",
                        dataType: 'json'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

One other thing that I noticed in the docs is that you may need to specify an HTTP request type, such as `POST` or `GET`.

[Here's the link to the pertinent part of the docs...](http://formvalidation.io/settings/#form-row-add-validating-class)

EDIT: [Here is documentation that is more pertinent, while the other one is more of an example.](http://formvalidation.io/validators/remote/)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer Tjons. It is nice to see that somebody actually is helping here, instead of writing my question is off topic. I will look into it right now

Comment: That is true I did not see that. I will just correct my code with this aswell.